# Array size in C# determine

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

First of all i'm novice to C#. How to determine array size in C# ? with the if condition check.

Normally php do like this,

```
if((sizeof($NewArray)==3) && (strtolower($NewArray[1])=='dddd'))
```

I just tried it out like this,

```
 If(NewArray.Length)==3) && (
```

After that i'm stucking ....

Comment: As a side note to the main answer, it's considered bad practice to use `ToLower()` when what you want to do is make a case insensitive string comparison. It's not too bad when done once or twice, but in a method that's called many times, it could cause performance problems since `ToLower` create and allocates a new string every time. You can use `myString.Equals("secondString", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`, which is a bit bulkier, but smarter.

Comment: Your question Title is incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `ToLower()` method?

```
if (newArray.Length == 3 && newArray[1].ToLower() == "dddd") ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what part you are stuck with so I shall explain all the parts I think I can see.

It looks like you are looking for the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) syntax on arrays.

The code you may want is:

```
if (NewArray.Length == 3 && NewArray[1].ToLower() == "dddd")
```

Note the square brackets [] indexing into the array. Regular C# arrays exposes an `int` indexer. Once indexed, the dot-notation will give you access to the type inside the array, here I assume that the array is a `string[]`, hence we can do `NewArray[1].<string members here>`.

Note also that **array indexing in C# is zero-based**, so 0 is the first element of the array and `NewArray.Length - 1` is the last element. Your `[1]` may not be correct *unless* of course you intend on accessing the second array item.

As a side note, using `ToLower` is not the only way to get case-insensitive comparisons, you can also do the following:

```
string.Compare(NewArray[1], "dddd", true) == 0
```

The [`string.Compare` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) shows the `ignoreCase` argument. I'm not in any way trying to say my suggestion is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //in php
 if((sizeof($NewArray)==3) && (strtolower($NewArray[1])=='dddd'))

 //in C#
 if ((NewArray.Length == 3) && (NewArray[1].ToLower() == "dddd"))
```

Comment: This won't compile because `(NewArray[1] == "ddd")` returns a boolean and there is no ToLower() on bool.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if( NewArray.Length== 3 && NewArray[1].ToLower() =="dddd")
```